# Where can I find recent scientific literature about Esperanto?

Tags: culture, science

I recently signed up to ResearchGate and started following Ilona Koutny, Federico Gobbo and some researchers that I know. Are there any other places or ways to stay up to date on Esperanto research?

Comment: Who can read German (I know you can ;-)) will find a lot of scientific literature on Interlinguistics, mostly Esperanto, in German here: http://www.interlinguistik-gil.de/wb/pages/tagungsakten.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good places to start are:

- [Google Scholar Alerts](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_alerts?view_op=create_alert_options&alert_query=Esperanto) (not Google Alerts, which I mention below), where you can be notified by email each time the term “Esperanto” is mentioned in a new scholarly article.

For more expansive results, you can scour:

- Google Alerts, but configure it to alert you by email (or RSS if you’re logged in to a Google account) only when Esperanto is mentioned in news content:

  1. Visit this [Google Alerts](https://www.google.com/alerts?hl=en&q=Esperanto) link.
  2. Where the “Sources” option is set to “Automatic”, change it to select only “News”.